# If Javascript code gets executed line by line then, how AST (Abstract syntax tree) works?

Tags: javascript, abstract-syntax-tree, machine-code, interpreted-language, compiled-language

Javascript is an interpreted language which executes code line by line. On the other hand, AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) inside the Javascript engine, created the data structure of the whole code and converts into machine code. Then how line by line mechanism is being applied here?

Comment: Just to save time - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-v8-compiles-javascript-code/

Comment: What makes you think it's interpreted line by line?

Comment: @Barmar, Thank you for your response.  from https://www.javatpoint.com/how-does-javascript-work I found below
"JavaScript is an interpreted language that means it gets executed in line by line manner (or which means the JavaScript engine converts the Js code line by line and runs in the same manner instead of converting the whole program once)."

Comment: It's more complicated than that. See the link @phuzi provided.

Comment: The quoted sentence is just totally wrong. Which is not uncommon for that site.